# How to handle login redirection with a http GET

Tags: powershell, oauth, screen-scraping, azure-iot-central

Context: I want to Screen Scrape an Azure IoT Central App page, to automate a process. If I go to to the page in the Edge Browser (Chrome Version required), it redirects to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize  where you complete the login (or select a previous login) and it then returns and renders the page.
Subsequent attempts to get the page in a browser on the same machine, do so without a further login. If I instead do an az login before the first attempt to get the page, the redirection still occurs.

If I try to GET that page contents (as string for scraping) at a Windows CMD prompt using curl, or in PowerShell using Invoke-webrequest  or Invoke-RestMethod, you get the login page. I have tried adding credentials to the command lines without any success. For example:

```
curl  -X GET "https://mycentralNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN.azureiotcentral.com/"  -u <user>
Get a prompt to enter password , which is entered
It then wants to redirect for login:
Redirecting to https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<ID>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fauth.azureiotcentral.com%2F_web%2Fuser%2Flogin%2Freturn&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fmanagement.azure.com%2F&response_type=code&response_mode=form_post&state=iotcentral.loginstate.<login state>
```

But nothing further appears appears.

In PowerShell you just get as content, the login page.

So my question is: Is there a way of handling this login redirection so as to get the content of the target page?

Comment: Some quick ideas: Do you want -X?  Use -L will follow redirect.  The login page will probably set a cookie, so maybe you want to use a -c?

Comment: Thanks.  With  -L instead of -X with -c .. the outcome is as with PowerShell: You get the login page html.

Comment: The page contains a piece of javascript with a json payload which contains session specific unique items (like a flowtoken) which need to be posted (in fact, it takes like 2 or 3 POST requests to complete the login flow and aquire the oauth token needed to do further requests on the azure page. I know this because I've reverse engineered this login flow for some production scripts. My tip: use a tool like Fiddler to inspect all the requests so you can recreate them

Comment: I am wondering if an api-token as per:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/azure-iot/iot/central/api-token?view=azure-cli-latest#ext_azure_iot_az_iot_central_api_token_list could be used   OR https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iotcentral/apitokens/get#apitoken ??